# Cross compiling FFTW for ARM Neon

Tags: gcc, arm64, fftw

I am trying to compile FFTW3 to run on ARM Neon (More precisely, on a Cortex a-53). The build env  is x86_64-pokysdk-lunix, The host env is aarch64-poky-lunix. I am using the aarch64-poky-linux-gcc compiler.
I used the following command at first:

> `./configure --prefix=/build_env/neon/neon_install_8 --host=aarch64-poky-linux --enable-shared --enable-single --enable-neon --with-sysroot=/opt/poky/2.5.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux "CC=/opt/poky/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+simd -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon"`

The compiler did not support the `-mfloat-abi=softfp` and the `-mfpu=neon`. It also did not let me define the path to the sysroot this way.
Then used the following command:

> `./configure --prefix=/build_env/neon/neon_install_8 --host=aarch64-poky-linux --enable-shared --enable-single --enable-neon "CC=/opt/poky/2.5.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-gcc" "CFLAGS=--sysroot=/opt/poky/2.5.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux -mcpu=cortex-a53 -march=armv8-a+simd"`

This command succeeded with this [config log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FL9K5rMUS7NRW6KMl9AGH_9z8LKx5di3/view?usp=sharing) and this [config.h](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SN4-CNTRTF_Nby1FFW_L4boYNLUmyamf/view?usp=sharing). Then I used the command `make` then `make install`. I then copied my shared library file into my host env and used `fftwf_` instead of `fftw_` in my code base. The final step was to recompile the program. I ran a test and compared the times for both algorithm using `<sys/resource.h>`. I also used the `fftw[f]_forget_wisdom()` on both algorithms so that It can be fair. However, I am not getting a speedup. I believe that using an SIMD architecture (`NEON` in our case) would accelerate the FFTW library.
I would really appreciate if anyone can point out something that I am  doing wrong so that I can try a fix and see if I can get the performance boost I am looking for.

Comment: Every ARM64 machine supports "NEON" SIMD; it's not an optional extension as was the case for ARM32.  So there's a good chance that the compiler was already using it before you tried to explicitly enable it, hence no change in performance.

Comment: Thank you for help. In my case, FFTW supports two mode. one without SIMD and one with. By default, SIMD is disabled. It must be enabled. Also, the one without SIMD seems to run faster